# Sprite not showing sfml

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml

I want to display my player in the window but my player sprite is not showing in the window. I am new to c++. I want to learn classes, inheritence, composition, etc in this way.I have 3 files Player.cpp, Game.cpp and main.cpp. I am using main.cpp to call Game.cpp using a fuction called Run().

Got nothing to try.

***Player.cpp***

```
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>


void Player::initPlayer()
{
    const char* playerTexturePath = "/Users/don/Desktop/sfmlgames/game1/img/MCmid.png";
    if(!mPlayerTexture.loadFromFile(playerTexturePath))
    {
        std::cout << "mPlayerTexturePath not found!!" << std::endl;
    }
    mPlayerSprite.setTexture(mPlayerTexture);
    mPlayerSprite.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    mPlayerSprite.setScale(1.f, 1.f);
}

void Player::draw_player(sf::RenderWindow &win)
{
    win.draw(mPlayerSprite);
}
```

***Game.cpp***

```
#include "Game.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Player player1;

//Constructor: Create a window and Player
Game::Game() : mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Game")
{
    //Frame rate 60
    mWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);  
    player1.initPlayer();
    }

//Game loop
void Game::Run()
{

    while(mWindow.isOpen())
    {
        
        render();
        events();
        update();
        
    }
}



void Game::events()
{
    sf::Event event;
    
    while (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            mWindow.close();
        }

    }
}

void Game::update()
{
    
}


void Game::render()
{   
    mWindow.clear(sf::Color::Red);
    player1.draw_player(mWindow);
    mWindow.display();
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "Game.hpp"

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.Run();
}
```

I don't think I will need to give code to hpp files.

Comment: The major problem with learning "classes, inheritence, composition, etc in this way" is that, simultaneously, one also needs to learn SFML, which is a very technical, specialized library that requires that someone already knows "classes, inhertence, composition, etc..." before using it. If you'd like to learn core fundamentals of C++, it will be much easier to use a classical C++ textbook that teaches these concepts, one step a time, without requiring advance knowledge of highly technical topics, like multimedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with image I dont know why. I used another image and it worked fine.